# Should Grails 3.x plugin name always include 'org.grails.plugins:'?

Tags: grails, grails-plugin, grails-3.0

Are Grails 3.x plugin names supposed to be `org.grails.plugins:$project.name` or just `$project.name`?

The default from https://raw.githubusercontent.com/grails/grails-profile-repository/master/profiles/plugin/templates/bintrayPublishing.gradle is `org.grails.plugins:$project.name`, but at https://bintray.com/grails/plugins/ some plugins include `org.grails.plugins:` and some do not.

As far as I can see there is no clear pattern that "official" plugins include `org.grails.plugins:` and third party plugins don't.

Update: bintrayPublishing.gradle referenced above has now changed the default name to `$project.group:$project.name`. The name is just a name, it is not used for dependency resolution in any way. But with the latest changes it is easier to see what the maven groupId and artifactId is.

Update 2: bintrayPublishing.gradle has changed the default again, now it's just `$project.name`. Starting from Grails 3.1 bintrayPublishing.gradle has been replaced by a [plugin](https://github.com/grails/grails-core/tree/master/grails-gradle-plugin). See also question 2 in [this blog post](http://blog.agileorbit.com/2015/10/07/Publishing-Grails-3-Plugins.html)

Answer (score 0):

i am using grails 3.0.5

after i trying to install plugin... i am become know..like this..

```
compile "org.grails.plugins:mail:2.0.0.RC2" ==> this plugin from grails.org

compile 'org.apache.activemq:activemq-spring:5.11.1' ==> this plugin from activemq.apache.org

compile "com.sun.mail:javax.mail:1.5.1" ==> this plugin look like from oracle
```

so not all plugin must include `org.grails.plugins`

Comment: That's the maven groupId. My question was about the Bintray name.